# How can I add claims to a JWT assigned with auth0 for a machine-to-machine application type?

Tags: auth0, openid-connect

I am using auth0 as OIDC provider for single-sign-on.

So far I tried login with two application types, on the one hand the **native** application type and on the other hand the **machine-to-machine** application type.

However, when I login, I only receive a very simple `id_token` with the following payload:

```
{
  "https://example.com/roles": [
    "user"
  ],
  "iss": "https://my.idp.provider.com",
  "sub": "oauth2|someconnection|samlp|somecompany|someusername",
  "aud": "REMOVED",
  "iat": 1547652649,
  "exp": 1547688649
}
```

I want to add a `group` claim to this token. How can I configure my Auth0 tenant to add `"group": "admin"` as claims? Do I need to enable a particular *scope* in my authentication client to receive the `groups` claim?

I have installed and configured the *Authorization Extension* in auth0 but that did not have any effect on the claims in my token. I know that the *Authorization Extension* does not support machine-to-machine applications. Therefore, I added the native application and tried to login with that, but that also did not return any additional claims.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After configuring the Authorization extension, you can add custom claims to the issued JWT tokens from Rules. There's a sample rule here that does the job: https://auth0.com/docs/extensions/authorization-extension/v2/rules#add-custom-claims-to-the-issued-token

You can customize the Client Credentials token as well using the Hook: https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/client-credentials/customize-with-hooks

EDIT: OIDC Comformant Apps require you to define the namespace because Authorization data such as roles and groups are not OIDC claims.

Comment: Is it possible to add a `groups` claim directly to the JWT without adding any URL as namespace prefix?

Comment: OIDC Conformant Apps require you to define the namespace because Authorization data such as roles and groups are not OIDC claims.

Comment: Yes, I had not considered that. Feel free to post an answer explaining that and I will upvote it.

Comment: Hey, glad I could help you. I added the answer to the original answer. Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible to customize the Client Credentials token via a Rule (and not via a Hook) as well?